# pandas pivot_table() with multiindex

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with information on movie
columns are: rating, gender, age, occupation, zip , movie_title

If I perform a pivot table as following

```
df.pivot_table('rating', index = 'title', columns = ["occupation",'gender'], aggfunc ='mean')
```

Does it automatically calculate the average of rating by each gender and then place it under corresponding occupation? Looking at the result, this seems correct, but I just want to be sure.

[image: The result]

Comment: I think code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think code is correct, should be simplify with omit `aggfunc`, because default function is `np.mean`:

```
df = df.pivot_table('rating', index = 'title', columns = ["occupation",'gender'])
```

Also you can specify each parameter:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'title', 
                    columns = ["occupation",'gender'],
                    values='rating')
```